# Find common and uncommon inequalities in two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists of inequalities:

```
l1={a>b&&c>d}
l2={a>b&&c<d}
```

Meaning that, some inequalities in the lists are the same, while other inequalities are the opposite.

I have tried with Intersection, which only gives me an empty set. What I want is like the following:

```
Common[l1,l2]={a>b}
Uncommon[l1,l2]={c>d,c<d}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method, there should be others.

If you try `FullForm` on `l1` and on `l2` you will see that those are of the form `List[And[a>b,c>d]]` and to do intersection and complement we need to get rid of that `And` which we can do in the following way:

```
l1={a>b&&c>d};
l2={a>b&&c<d};
newl1=l1/.{p_&&q_}->{p,q};
newl2=l2/.{p_&&q_}->{p,q};
common=Intersection[newl1,newl2]
uncommon=Complement[Join[newl1,newl2],common]
```

which returns

```
{a>b}
```

and

```
{c>d,c<d}
```

Try that very carefully and check that in lots of cases to make certain that it is correct.

Answer (score 3):

```
x = {a > b && c > d};

y = {a > b && c < d};
```

Using `MapApply` (new in 13.1)

```
z = First @* MapApply[List] /@ {x, y}
```

{{a > b, c > d}, {a > b, c < d}}

Using `SymmetricDifference` (new in 13.1) to get the uncommon elements

```
SymmetricDifference @@ z
```

{c > d, c < d}

Using `Intersection` to get the common elements

```
Intersection @@ z
```

{a > b}

Answer (score 2):

```
x = {a > b && c > d};

y = {a > b && c < d};
```

---

Using `List` and `MapApply`:

```
z = List @@@ Catenate@{x, y}

(*{{a > b, c > d}, {a > b, c < d}}*)
```

Using `DeleteCases` and `Alternatives` to get the uncommon elements:

```
Join @@ DeleteCases[#1, Alternatives @@ #2] & @@@ Permutations[z]

(*{c > d, c < d}*)
```

Using `Counts` to get the common elements:

```
Keys@Select[Counts[Flatten@z], # > 1 &]

(*{a > b}*)
```